# flutter integration text resource

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any package for integration text resource like `Android` `xml` string resource in `flutter`?

I think about create file `Constant.dart` and defined some `const` value inside.

**Constant.dart**

```
const USER_NAME = "firstname";
const USER_LAST_NAME = "lastname";
```

Comment: You already looked this? https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/xml

Comment: Which way better!?

Comment: XML is standardized, will facilitate code maintenance. Constant.dart easier, but I see as a "quick fix".